# cannot retrieve integer from intent in android broadcastreceiverclass

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am new to android development and trying to make my first app. When I send an `Intent` with Extras from an `Activity` to `BroadcastReceiver`, I need to get its extras but broadcastreceiver is not supporting `getIntent().getExtras()`.

Comment: It's better if you show your code. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BroadcastReceivers will give you the intent, you just have to get the extras from it. Override the onReceive method to get the intent as a parameter:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    //do something with the extras
}
```